# SQL select Exist partly

Tags: sql, select

have a list (table) of `PROJECTNUMBERS` with different length, for example:

```
 123   
 1254   
 25-135
```

then I have a (Long) list (table) of `DRAWINGNUMBERS` with valid and invalid values.

Valid are those that begin with a Projectnumber (see above),

```
valid:  
123-78787  
123-78799  
25-135.115-15  
25-135-511  


invalid  
1841  
Anything else
```

I try to use

```
select * from DRAWINGNUMBERS where exit ??? PROJECTNUMBER
```

This does not succeed, as EXIST or IN... always exect to find the value.
However I can not use LEFT(..) as the PROJECTNUMBERS have different length.

**ASK:**
Any idea, how to select valid drawingnumbers?

Comment: Where did you get `EXIT` from?

Comment: Can you please tag  the DBMS you are using like SQLServer/mysql/oracle...

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: EXIT was typo, meant EXIST   ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical method uses `exist` or `join`.  Here is one method:

```
select d.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from projects p
                          where d.drawingnumber like concat(p.projectnumber, '%')
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as validFlag
from drawings d;
```

I prefer `exists` because two projects might match the same drawing . . . say "12" and "123".  The `join` would produce multiple rows.

I should note that not all databases support the `concat()` function . . . you can use `+` or `||` or `&` depending on your database.